# How to check if "State Service application" is installed or not

Tags: 2013, powershell, service, state

I want to know by some powershell script if "State Service application" is installed or not? I have some other script to run but before running that script, i want to check if "State Service application" is installed or not, so that i can install if it is not installed. How i check using powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below PowerShell script let you know whether 'State Service' application is running or not.
Provide your State Service Application Name against $ServiceName" variable.

```
$ServiceName = "State Service Application"
$serviceApp = Get-SPStateServiceApplication -Identity $ServiceName
 Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkGray "Checking if "  $ServiceName  " instance is Online"
 if($serviceApp.Status -ne "Online")
 {
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $ServiceName " instance is not running"   
 }
 else
 { 
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $ServiceName " instance is already running"
 }
```

I have created an article on my blog to start/stop Search Service Application based on the current state of the application.

http://sharepointcore.blogspot.in/2015/03/how-to-check-whether-service.html

Comment: I have modified the question please have a look. i don't want to check if it is running or not but i want to check if it is installed or not ?